# NginX Subdomains

Tags: nginx

Working on migrating servers and having zero luck setting up my subdomains.  The behavior I'm looking for is fairly straightforward:

- www.domain.com & domain.com --> /var/www/live/
- *.domain.com --> /var/www/*/ (assuming the sub directory exists, otherwise redirect to main site)

I've tried using $host in a couple of configurations and I've tried using many variations of:

`server_name   ~^(.*)\.domain\.com$;`

`root /var/www/$1;`

and

`server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.domain\.com$;`

`root /var/www/$subdomain`;

This is basic NginX behavior but I'm completely stumped and I've wasted way too many hours trying to hack my way through this.  Can anyone shed some light on the solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that using $host in this way will cause the variable to be evaluated at every request. If you have a static number of subdomains, consider writing vhosts.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;
    root /var/www/example.com/$subdomain;
    set $subdomain "";
    if ($host ~* ^([a-z0-9-\.]+)\.example.com$) {
        set $subdomain $1;
    }
    if ($host ~* ^(www.)?example.com$) {
        set $subdomain "live";
    }

}
```

Comment: No dice, but I'll try to play with a couple variations of this.

Answer (score 3):

Your second `server_name` directive looks correct and should work (and is the nicest solution IMHO). The [documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server_name) suggests the following syntax for older PCRE versions, so you could try this:

```
server_name ~^(?P<subdomain>.+)\.domain\.com$;
root /var/www/$subdomain;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Other people are using map](http://jokull.calepin.co/nginx-mass-dynamic-hosting.html) to help solve this problem. Here are [direct docs for map](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMapModule#map).

Some other things to check: Check the version of you Nginx you are using against the latest version. If you are reading the documentation online, they may be referencing newer behaviors than the ones you actually having.

Also, it's my understanding that the backreference syntax like `?<subdomain>` is enabled in part from `libpcre`. Check `man pcrepattern` and see if it has a section on "NAMED SUBPATTERNS".

Comment: I have complied NginX 1.2.0 with the latest PCRE library.  Map looks promising - I'm reading up on it now.

Comment: this variant have an advantage of using txt file for cname->username association. But it also will be slightly slower under load.